# Stop the loading icon according to the completion of the template async pipe

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular7, ionic4

*.ts*

```
  init() {
    const loading = await this.loadingService.presentLoader();//loading
    this.products$ = this.bikeShopService.get();//Observable operation
  }
```

*.html*

```
  <ion-col size="6" *ngFor="let p of (products$ | async)?.result[0]?.categories[0]?.ShoppingCart;">
        <app-bike-shop-item [data]="p"></app-bike-shop-item>
   </ion-col>
```

*loading.service.ts*

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoadingService {

  constructor(private loadingCtrl: LoadingController) { }

  async presentLoader(message = 'Please wait...'): Promise<HTMLIonLoadingElement> {
    const loader = await this.loadingCtrl.create({
      message: message,
    });
    loader.present();
    return loader;
  }

  dismissLoader(loader: HTMLIonLoadingElement): Promise<boolean> {
    if (loader) { return loader.dismiss(); }
  }
}
```

**Q:** Can you tell me how can I stop the `loading icon` according to the completion of the `subscription`? Since I use template `async` pipe I don't have `.ts` file completion event (i.e. `subscription`). 
I can use the duration parameter. But it is an obviously bad option since we cannot guarantee the data receivable time.

Answer (score 1):

```
this.products$ = this.bikeShopService.get().pipe(

     tap( product=>   { 
               // do something here to notify that data is successfully retrieved
         }        
    )
)
```